# Programmatically executing Artisan CLI commands failing in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to execute Artisan CLI command in a Laravel controller using programming conditional logic(if/else). In other words, I'm trying to execute Artisan CLI command through using HTTP request/response cycle. However, when I'm using a form submission to do this I get this error:

```
Spatie\DbDumper\Exceptions\DumpFailed thrown with message "The dump 
process failed with exitcode 2 : Misuse of shell builtins : sh: 1: 
cannot create 
/var/www/html/DC_for_Rony/dc/storage/app/Laravel/dump.sql: 
Permission denied 
"
```

I've already researched everything online about this issue. Unfortunately none of them satisfied with the correct solution that I need.

DBBackupController.php(for Programming Logic, I'm only stating the function):

```
    public function auth_bkp(Request $request){
        if (Auth::user()) {
          if (Auth::user()->role == 3 && $request->pass == 
            'dc_for_rony') {
              // dd('1');
              Artisan::call(BackupDatabase::class,array());
              return back()->with('yesss!!');
          }else{
              //dd('2');
            return back()->with('sorry!');
          }
        }else{

        }
   }
```

config/database.php(for Configuration Issues Just the mysql driver):

```
   'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', ''),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', ''),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'dump' => [
           'dump_binary_path' => '/usr/bin', // only the path, so 
            without `mysqldump` or `pg_dump`
           'use_single_transaction',
           'timeout' => 60 * 5, // 5 minute timeout
           'exclude_tables' => ['table1', 'table2'],
           'add_extra_option' => '--optionname=optionvalue', 
        ]
    ],
```

I'm expecting to generate the Artisan CLI command if the logic suffices. My mysqldump is already installed.Can anybody help?

Comment: Does this folder `app/Laravel/` in your storage have the write permission?

Comment: As error showing here is just a permission issue.

Comment: According to your error the problem is not in the code but in the file itself. You don't have permissions for it to write.

Comment: Yes, it was a file permission issue in storage/app/Laravel Directory. I had recursive 775 (including write) permission. However, it was owned by my user account, not www-data for which this error was throwing, so I had to change the ownership of that directory. Anyways, the problem is solved. Thanks.